# Xpath: more than an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

This is my first question.

I'd like to do a query on this XML file that returs every element with more than one attribute:

[XML image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRNI4.png)

How do I do that?

Comment: What are you interested in? It's not clear from your question. Please, make a concrete example: what element would you like to select?

Comment: The XPath sentence that returns every element with more than one attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use count(attribute::*)

```
//*[count(attribute::*)>1]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a document like this

```
<a>
<b attr1="x"></b>
<c attr1="x" attr2="y"></c>
<c attr1="x" attr2="y"></c>
<c attr1="x" attr2="y"></c>
<d attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z"></d>
<e></e>
</a>
```

then

```
//*[count(@*) >1]
```

will return you

```
<c attr1="x" attr2="y"/>
<c attr1="x" attr2="y"/>
<c attr1="x" attr2="y"/>
<d attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z"/>
```